# cURL works on cli but not in php

Tags: php, curl

This works perfectly on the command line:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Authorization:Bearer <authkey>" \
  -d '{"intent":"sale","redirect_urls":{"return_url":"https:\/\/devtools-paypal.com\/guide\/pay_paypal\/curl?success=true","cancel_url":"https:\/\/devtools-paypal.com\/guide\/pay_paypal\/curl?cancel=true"},"payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"7.47","currency":"USD"},"description":"This is the payment transaction description."}]}'
```

and then in php I have the following

```
    <?php

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "Content-Type:application/json");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "Authorization:Bearer <authkey>");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"intent":"sale","redirect_urls":{"return_url":"https:\/\/devtools-paypal.com\/guide\/pay_paypal\/curl?success=true","cancel_url":"https:\/\/devtools-paypal.com\/guide\/pay_paypal\/curl?cancel=true"},"payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"7.47","currency":"USD"},"description":"This is the payment transaction description."}]}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $res = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    ?>
    <pre>
    <?php print_r($res); ?>
    </pre>
```

However this only prints `<pre></pre>` and no response whatsoever.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you install de php curl extension? http://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5

Comment: yes I have other curl scripts that run fine

Comment: check `phpinfo()` (or `$ php -i | grep curl` on CLI), and make sure the curl extension is installed... if that's not the problem, check `curl_error` and `curl_errno`'s output

Comment: Why are you using CURLOPT_ENCODING instead of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Comment: I have no idea, just something I looked up.  I will try the program using the HEADER constant

Comment: @marian0 You my friend are an angel.  Please post an answer so I can give you rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER instead of CURLOPT_ENCODING.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Authorization:Bearer <authkey>"));
```